# Is there a way to execute robocopy cmd from a Stored Procedure in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, cmd, dbms-scheduler

I have to move certain files from a local directory(which is fixed) into another server. I can use robocopy from Windows cmd line to do the same. Is there a way in which i can create a job which executes this specific windows cmd for me in ORacle Pl/SQL? Also, can i include this in a stored procedure?

Comment: Why would you involve a **database** into the **file transfer** operation? The fact that you can do it, doesn't mean that you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

try to use DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_ftran.htm#CACFJEBH